# Display value to a certain number of decimal places in a VBA userform

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently creating a userform in VBA where you input numbers, press calculate, and then the answer is returned in a textbox.

Currently the answer is being displayed to 10+ significant figures (see below). What would I need to do to make my calculated output display only 3 decimal places?

Thanks!

---

Calculation output example:

[image: Calculation Output Example]

Comment: You want the floor function. Please add some code so we can answer this. If you can't add code at least submit some pseudo code or dummy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format(myAnswer, "0.00")` will do it if you want 2 digits after the decimal point, just add more or less `0`'s after the decimal point in the second argument to change the significant figures.

[Here](http://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel/) is a website about how to write number formats to use in this function.

Comment: No problem buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Try: `TextBox1 = Round(Value, 3)`